# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: support, comments, moderation

I remember that I had posted one comment under this question: [Are scriptures censored?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/49000/4732).
But when I checked the post later I did not find the comment there. Currently there are few comments present under that post but my comment isn't there.

Can Mods please explain what was the reason it was deleted?

Comment: Seems to be becoming a recent nuisance on the site. [Why have the comments on this question been deleted?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2331/20129). —> Sure you must’ve seen this.

Comment: Yes, I have seen your post. Let the mods explain why those comments were deleted. @Adiyarkku

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comment was deleted by a CM since they(correctly) felt it was an attempt to post an answer as a comment, but upon reflection, the mod team decided it should be undeleted because we allow comment-answers in some cases.

Cases where we allow comment-answers are:

1. When we know answer but lack references. **[Such is the case in the said link of the question post.]**
2. When we receive valid **convert-answer-to-comment** flag.

However at the same time we would like to remind that it is not a good practice to continue posting answers in comments as per general SE policy.

A general note for every user:

**Help section** on [***comments***](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) already covers what's allowed and what is not. If you already know basic stuffs like how to comment, then simply scroll to most important parts **"When should I comment?"** and **"When shouldn't I comment?"**

Comment: 1. On one hand we have the general SE guidelines and on the other we have site specific guidelines too for sites like ours. And, we haven't reached a consensus yet that such comments should be deleted at first sight. 2. Since when CMs started deleting comments like this (I assume they weren't even flagged)? That's highly surprising. I think it never happened before even for once. It should be left to us, the users and Mods of the site, to delete posts/comments by flagging and that IMO is the correct way.